# Backup Strategy in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure

Do we have any standard way of daily backing up SQL Azure databases to onprim?
I know about the option of making backups to Storage, but on a daily basis, if we backup on storage blobs we will end up having many files and it will incur a high cost with Azure.

1. We need to take backup of SQL Azure Databases directly to onprim disks.
2. Maintain only two latest backups on the disk.

Do we have mechanism to schedule daily backup to storage blob and maintain only two copies at any moment of time?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the new SQL Database Point-in-time feature is good to you. You need to enable this preview feature and select a new edition when creating your database. "Basic" edition support daily backup stores in the past 24 hours while "Standard" and "Premium" editions provides point-in-time backup stores backups in the past 7 days and 35 days.

Alternatively you need to pragmatically backup the database in blob and remove the old ones through worker role, scheduler, webjob.